# PHP time&date parse and difference

Tags: php, date

I have a PHP string of the following form: *"[Fri, 23 Nov 2012 20:00:18 +0000]"*

I'd like to ask how much time passed since then, if it's 1 day and 5 hours etc.
How can I do it efficiently?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = str_replace(array('[',']'),'',"[Fri, 23 Nov 2012 20:00:18 +0000]");

$diff = date_diff(date_create() , date_create($date));

echo $diff->format("Difference: %Y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s");
```

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way is to convert the string into unix timestamp and do your logic based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->d;
?>
```

[DateTime in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

Function **strtotime** returned unixtime for your string
Function **time** return unixtime for current time.
Both function return time in seconds. You cat subtracts it and get interval in seconds

```
<?php
$logtime = strtotime("Fri, 23 Nov 2012 20:00:18 +0000");
$interval = time() - $logtime;
printf("Interval is: %d hours, %d minutes, %d sec.", 
        $interval/3600, ($interval%3600)/60, $interval%60);
?>
```